# Is it possible to block subsequent PRs until the current PR is successfully deployed to ECS?

Tags: github-actions, devops, aws-codepipeline

We have a service that uses github, AWS ECR and ECS, also use github action to make the flow work.

Is it possible to disable the rest PRs' mergebility until the current one is successfully deployed to ECS?

I tried to apply Github Branch rule such as CI must pass and codepipeline execution need to success. But that seems only target to the current PR and won't affect the rest PR that are still waiting to be approved.

Assume the codepipeline fails for the current PR in test stage, how can I use this result to disable rest PR's mergebility? SNS seems an option? How can I let github listen to this SNS?

Tried to use a script that listens to the status of current codepipeline, but the fail result won't affect other PR's mergebility.

Also github shows this message:
*github expected — waiting for status to be reported*

From where should this be reproted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of labels and GitHub Actions to block the PR from merging:

```yaml
name: Do Not Merge

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [synchronize, opened, reopened, labeled, unlabeled]

jobs:
  do-not-merge:
    if: ${{ contains(github.event.*.labels.*.name, 'do not merge') }}
    name: Prevent Merging
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check for label
        run: |
          echo "Pull request is labeled as 'do not merge'"
          echo "This workflow fails so that the pull request cannot be merged"
          exit 1
```

Using this Action, you just apply a label containing the text `do not merge` to your PR, and the PR will be blocked until the label is removed.

To integrate this into the pipeline, you would need to do a few things:

1. When the pipeline starts running, iterate through all PRs and append the label to all, except the current one
2. When the pipeline completes (including failure) remove the label from all PRs.
3. Create another action that upon PR creation checks for the right conditions (e.g. pipeline with deployment running) and if the conditions are met, appends the correct label to this branch plus terminates the run.

You can still find yourself in race conditions, at which point you should consider centralizing all this logic into a custom GitHub App, and manage state from there. (Via some BE that can manage locking properly)

The question is extremely specific, and the right solution should tie into your pipeline nicely, so I don't think a generic (reusable) answer can easily be provided.

Source: https://www.neilmacy.co.uk/blog/github-action-to-block-merging